# Optimisation of Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization, view

I have a windows service that gets data from views and for each view, a table has been defined in which the data is filled.

The views are made such that there are views inside views may be upto three level deeper.

Can you give me some tips how to improve performance of the outer most views ?

Or how to improve performance overall.

Thanks.

**EDIT** : I have also heard its not good strategy to use view inside view, is it true ?

Answer (score 3):

- Views are macros
- They expand at run time
- They do not encapsulate or pre-calculate queries **
- They are not optimisations
- DRY doesn't always apply to databases (the case for views as presented by client developers)

Basically, remove the views. You usually don't need them.

For general performance tuning, this is a different and complex question and it usually starts with a bad design and bad code and bad practices.

** indexed or materialised views do, but these have usage limitations

Answer (score 2):

Performance in overall is not affected with the structure of views

**EXCEPT**

if you use some aggregates processing inside(or anything not just selecting the fields) or forces query optimizer **NOT** to expand views.

What about strategy of views inside views - tastes matters, I think that it is not beautiful, but I cannot name it as a strategy 8-)

And a few words about **improve performance overall** - it is the **MOST** complicated area to answer it within one message, I think you should start to tune your DB for performance gain without special focusing on views or views inside others or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think here it is explained very well [View Performance Question](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=84241)

> SQL Server resolves the total query at run time, so the query plan
>   will be like you wrote joins and selected the columns you wanted. If
>   the views contain only the joins that are appropriate for your query,
>   the performance should be no worse than writing the select statement.
>   If the view has joins that are not appropriate for the query you are
>   running, it can cause a performance problem.

Also, SQL Server spends some time on "looking into the view" (e.g. selecting data from the system tables), so execution time of view will be a little greater than of the same query, although their execution plans will be identical.